# Boot Problem - Cannot Install Edubuntu

Tags: boot, usb, system-installation, edubuntu

I have an old Toshiba laptop I'd like to put Edubuntu on.  I first made a DBAN disc to wipe the drive.  It was burned with Imgbrn software and booted fine.  I also made an Edubuntu disc in the same manner, but it will not boot.  The disc image file is from the Edubuntu website.

I then formatted a flash drive to make it bootable and used the Universal USB Installer at pendrivelinux.com to put Edubuntu on the flash drive.

The boot menu on the bios is set to 1) CD/DVD 2) Removable media, 3) Hard drive, 4) Network.  When the computer starts, it recognizes the flash drive, but when it cycles through the boot process, it gets to the last in the list as evidenced by the PXE error that eventually comes up when it can't find a network connection.

I know the computer can boot from disc as it booted the DBAN disc when I wiped the hard drive.  I don't know why it will not boot Edubuntu either from disc or from a flash drive.  This is my first experience with any Linux-based OS.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem.

On April 16, 2014, I downloaded Edubuntu version 12.04 from the Edubuntu.org website.  This is the file I have been trying to install.

As I continued to troubleshoot why it wouldn't boot, I learned that a newer version came out on April 17.  Tonight, I downloaded the newer version and it worked fine.  Apparently, something went wrong with the file I had initially downloaded.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. I'm glad you solved your problem. It's always ok to answer your own question. I'm also a big fan of Edubuntu, but try to keep answers focused on the facts. :)